# Set of diagonalizing matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a positive definite matrix. I would like to characterize the set
$$
\mathcal{A} := \{A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} : AMA' \text{ is diagonal and invertible} \}.
$$

Clearly one element of $\mathcal{A}$ is the orthogonal matrix given by the eigenvectors of $M$ and one can multiply it by a non-zero scalar to generate other elements. However I don't know whether these are the only elements.

Any help willbe highly appreciated!

Comment: I am assuming that with $A'$ you mean the inverse of $A$. Then the matrix $AMA'$ describes the linear map described by $M$ in the standard basis in the basis formed by the columns of $A'$. So $A'$ can be all the possible bases that are bases of eigenvectors of M. You have infinitely many choices for that because you can scale eacht vector of that basis or you can use linear combinations of eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue and so on...

Comment: I think $A'$ refers to the transpose of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can think about it. The operation $\left<x,y\right>_M  = x^TMy$ defines an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, the matrices $A$ such that $AMA'$ is diagonal will merely be the ones whose rows are orthogonal under this inner product.